# Fine to put as an appendix to my statement of purpose the paragraph explaining the gaps in my transcripts?

Tags: graduate-admissions, statement-of-purpose

I am applying to doctoral programs in the US, and, because I have two breaks in my studies as what shown in my transcripts, I want to find somewhere to explain these.

But I am concerned with that if I simply put this short paragraph explaining my breaks in studies somewhere in my application package as a supplemental material, then it may be ignored (would it?)! Thus I decided to include it in my statement of purpose as an appendix.

The number of the words in my statement of purpose is not a problem, for even when the paragraph is included, my statement of purpose still contains less than 800 words.

So would such deed of mine have any chances to annoy any member of the committees?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any way to turn the gaps into strengths as part of your narrative in the statement of purpose?  If so, that is likely better than separating them in an appendix.  For example, if you spent time in industry, did it give you a better appreciation of why you wanted to return to studies?  If you took time off for personal or family reasons, did it give you time to reflect or experiences that have shaped why you want to return to graduate school? More mature students who are in a graduate program because they really understand what they want out of it are often highly appreciated by professors.  If that is you, then embrace the gaps in your transcript and let them be (a small) part of your main narrative.

Answer (score 3):

This would be fine. One fundamental point of the personal statement is to allow you to comment on anything unusual in your records (gaps in education, a semester when you got sick and had low grades, etc.)

In general, you can format the statement of purpose however you like. Using clear signposts (such as section headings) can make it much easier to follow.

Remember that the person reading your personal statement probably has a large stack of them to read, so making their job easier can only help you.

Answer (score 2):

I would put such gaps in the diversity statement. That's what that optional portion is for -- showing how you are different from the norm. Many faculty prefer students who have had experience outside of school -- or who have left and then recommitted to coming back. So don't view this as just a negative.

When I read applications, I want the statement of purpose to be about the research you want to do. I do not like biographies -- the one's that start out with "When I was a little boy, I always wanted to be an ______" (or some similar iteration) get tossed out.